# How to force minimize or switch a video / game - Bug?

Tags: video, 13.04, games, application-switcher

I'm comming from Windows 7, and something that I loved there was to Alt+Tab in any Game or video and switch to another app without problem.

Here, I tried with Age of Mythology (Wine), that I play it a lot, and saw that it can't minimize it and switch to another app. Mouse pointer is in another side but you're seeing the game...

I though that was Wine's bug, but now I tried with a Video with standard Ubuntu 13.04 Video player. When it's on full screen I try to Alt+Tab, Ctrl+Super+D, and some other commands and it can't minimize or switch. I only see bugs when trying.......

Is not possible??? :O

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to switch out of fullscreen in Linux right now. Some apps will have a shortcut for it such as F11, Ctrl-f, Alt-Tab or Alt-Enter, but others do not and quitting them might be the only way and if they are buggy not even that might be possible.

For apps running in Wine there is however a workaround. If you run `winecfg` go to the `Graphics` tab and set `Emulate a virtual desktop` you can force all Windows applications to run in window mode. Furthermore you can use `wmctrl` to remove the borders of a window. I found that running applications in window mode and having this command bound to a key:

```
wmctrl -r ":ACTIVE:" -b toggle,fullscreen
```

Works quite well most of the time, as unlike fullscreen mode done by a game itself, this kind of fullscreen is done by the window manager and you retain normal Alt-Tab control. It however only works with games that run in the same resolution as your desktop.

I have also written some tools to further tweak fullscreen behavior:

https://github.com/Grumbel/fullscreen-tools

But they are not all that user-friendly, but might be interesting if you wanna tweak things a bit further, to disable decorations, keep a window on top and move it to 0,0 would look like this:

```
windowtool.py -d 0 -a 1 -m 0,0 ACTIVE
```